# How to add a more complex validator schema to mongoDB using mongocxx

Tags: c++, mongodb, schema, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm looking for a way to apply validator schema to my MongoDB collections using the API from mongocxx but the documentation about the required syntax for more complex schemas is lacking.

[Document Validation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/examples/mongocxx/document_validation.cpp)

Is there a more complete example somewhere?

Is there a way to read a json schema file and use it as a string to set a collection schema?

At the moment, I manually copy my collection schema generated from one of my serializing tool into MongoCompass but I need a way to apply the same schema from mongocxx.

Example json schema file :

```
{
  $jsonSchema: {
    properties: {
      someId: {
        type: 'number'
      },
      someVar: {
        type: 'number'
      },
      someOtherVar: {
        type: 'string'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried using the option parameter in the create_collection function and also the run_command but both will fail with some typing error where it expects an object where a string was provided.

```
db.run_command(make_document(
   kvp("collMod", tableName),
   kvp("validator", schemaFile.c_str())
));
```

Any idea how to proceed if it is even possible?
Thanks